# Accessing each word of a string using c++

Tags: c++, string

I was working on a program where I take input from the user in the form of string and then find its length using following syntax.

```
getline(cin,password); 
length=password.length();
```

The actual work of program is to do password validation, where it takes string input from user and only alphaneumeric characters are allowed( No symbols and spaces)

Now, if user enters 'symbols and spaces', I need to access each word of the string and let user know the entered string contains 'symbols and spaces' if any present,  but I dont know how to access each word of string.

Answer (score 2):

You can make good use of a regular expression to check your password, e.g. this expression ensures only lower- and uppercase letters and numbers are allowed in a given string: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` (beginning position `^` to end position `$`);

Sample code ([online test](https://ideone.com/ZHNF68)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

bool validateAlphaNumsOnly(std::string pw) {
    
    std::regex alphanum_only_regex { "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$" }; // expression beginning to end lower- and uppercase letters and numbers only

    if(std::regex_search(pw, alphanum_only_regex)) {
        std::cout << "That's a valid Password! " << pw << std::endl;
        return true;
    } else { 
        std::cout << "Invalid Password! " << pw << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {        
    validateAlphaNumsOnly("aaa abc");
    validateAlphaNumsOnly("aaaYYYabc");
    validateAlphaNumsOnly("aaaYYYabc1");
    return 0;
}
```

PS: We could check the length with the regex as well: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$` instead of one or more `+` chars we require 8 or more...

Comment: The OP wanted an alphanumeric rather than an alphabetic password. Still upvoted.

Comment: @Eugene thanks, corrected, I somehow I read 'letters only' first.

Comment: @wp78de thanks for this pretty quick solution but I am not yet familiar with regex. 

Answer (score 0):

Use this method, istream& get (char* s, streamsize n, char delim);
it takes characters into a c-string until n-1 characters have been typed or a terminating character, which you can make a space character.

```
char* str[50];
get(str, 50, " ");
int length = strlen(str);
```

regards,

Comment: I actually wanted to work with strings, I had already done a similar program in char arrays,  nevermind. Thank you for the efforts